# php mysql search error Couldn't execute query

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a php script to fetch data but somehow it has stopped working and giving Couldn't execute query, I am unable to find the problem.

```
//connect to your database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); //(host, username, password)

//specify database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
mysql_select_db("database") or die("Unable to select database");           //select which database we're using


$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE id = $id";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Couldn't execute");
```

Comment: You should tell us what the specific issue is. Did the system stop working? Don't you get any results any more? Did the universe implode? "is not working" does not really help...

Comment: Ask [mysql_error()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_error) about the specifics. (And while you're at it, please have a read of http://docs.php.net/mysql.php , esp. the part(s) about mysql_* being deprecated)

Comment: What you have in `$id` ?

Comment: This is old stuff. `mysql_connect` doesn't even exist anymore in PHP 7. If you're learning, please learn one of the newer replacements, like PDO. And also pay attention to the possible result values of the functions and the methods of getting extended error information. In your case anything could have gone wrong.

Comment: the same script was working earlier and fetching the data on the basis of id but suddenly it started giving the error Couldn't execute and dies, though the same script is fetching different set of data and is working perfectly

Comment: The comment was even vaguer than the question. What is the error according to MySQL ? What is the content of $id (both for when it works and when it doesn't)?

Comment: If it worked for you earlier, what changed causing it to stop?

Comment: Guys thanks I have figured it out, the problem was at $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE id = $id";

Comment: Thanks all of you for quick support :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used 2 times database name here. Just use this

```
$db_username = 'uname';
$db_password = 'password';
$db_name = 'db_name';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$db_select =mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
$db_=mysql_select_db($db_name,$db_select);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE id = $id";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Couldn't execute");
```